# How to make an animated plot to stop rolling back when reaching the last animation step?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph-visualization, gganimate

This is a reproducible example of an animated plot I made:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
Year, value
1970,0
1980,1500
1990,2300
2000,4000
2010,4200
2020,6000
")
  
ggplot(data = data.1 %>% mutate(Year=as.numeric(Year),
                                  value=as.numeric(value)), 
       mapping = aes(x = Year, 
                     y = value)) +
    geom_line() +
    transition_reveal(Year)
```

The animation is OK, but I would like to make it stop and not rollback when it reach the last year of visualization.
Is it possible to do that with `transition_reveal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render the gif you can set `loop = FALSE` like this:

```r
animate(myplot, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = FALSE))
```